# Running / Cumulative Total in DAX using only measures, no calculated columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Problem:

Create a running total measure that does not reference any calculated columns, only measures.

One measure is a calculation.
Another measure is auto-incrementing IDs created from a RANKX.

The goal is to create a running total measure/sum for A using reference only to B.

Context:
For data restriction reasons, there is no ability to add a calculated column. Therefore, there are a number of measures that have been created.

Existing trials:

Existing knowledge base (internet searches) only seem to refer to measures where there is a mixture of columns and measures. There is no ability to add calculated columns, however, nor need for/use of existing columns within this particular running total.

Currently there has been an attempt to use a table expression to build the table with the measures, creating additional variables for a max (MAXX) and trying to filter this way and use a CAlCULATE in the return. This is only returning the total and not a running total.

Edit:

Example table:

| [...existing cols] | Measure A | Measure B | (Needed) Measure C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 10 | 1 | 10 |
| ... | 60 | 2 | 70 |
| ... | 40 | 3 | 110 |

Measure A is a sum of other measures
Measure B is a rank of other measures
Measure C is a running total of measure A given Measure B

Comment: I'd recommend providing an example toy data table and corresponding measure to work with rather than requiring responders to invent them to answer.

Comment: is the RANKX measure given? if not what's the criteria for it?

Comment: @Alexis Olson, edited original question. The measures consist of other measures, I did not want to conflate the underlying question. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Stachu , good question. It exists within one of the existing measures to provide a ranking. The current attempt is a rolling total using only these measures. Hopefully the additional table  in the edit provides some context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic pattern for this is:

```
CumulativeMeasureA =
VAR CurrentRank = [MeasureB]
RETURN
    SUMX ( FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Group] ), [MeasureB] <= CurrentRank ), [MeasureA] )
```

Where `Data[Group]` is the column that you are grouping on in your report visual.

---

Note that this isn't very efficient without calculated columns since it is having to compute `[MeasureB]` for every `Group` for every row in your visual, filter those results, and compute `[MeasureA]` every iteration that isn't filtered out. For small datasets, this isn't a problem but can be as things get larger and more complex.

Comment: I was implementing the exact same thing using the Contoso model with 100K rows and I confirm that is veeeeery slow. :) But this is it.

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks Alexis! (@sergiom - Indeed, I am noticing that as well. It's also starting to seem very possible with the current dataset that this is a fast-track way to break PowerBI. :) )

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you find it useful avoiding the prior step of creating an independent measure for MeasureA:

```
Cummulative MeasureA=
VAR _CurrentRank=[MeasureB]
VAR _SomeTable=ADDCOLUMNS(FILTER(ALL(DataTable), [MeasureB]<=_CurrentRank),"Measure A Value",...whatever the formula for MeasureA should be, not the measure itself...)
RETURN 
SUMX(_SomeTable, [Measure A Value])
```